# Структурные типы/обёртки в kotlin над примитивами с перегруженными get & set

Tags: android, kotlin

хочу объявить MutableLiveData со своими геттером и сеттером у числа.
это можно сделать не создавая новый класс?
По идее если такой способ есть, он должен работать и для массивов.
т.е. я могу перегружать set/get примитивов какнибудь так:

```
var count: Long
    get() = if (чтото) field else 0
    set(value) {if (value>0) field = value}
```

и я хочу объявить LiveData состоящий из примитивов с моими сеттером и геттером.
Хочу чтобы снаружи элементы массива или `<LiveData>.value` воспринимались как Long, но при обращении к ним выполнялись мои get & set функции

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в общем, немного костыльное решение нашёл:

```
    private val pCount: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    fun observeCount(x: LifecycleOwner, y: Observer<in Int>) = pCount.observe(x,y)
    var count: Int
        get() = TODO(pCount.value)
        set(value) {pCount.value = TODO(value)}
```

обсервера вешаем на observeCount, а меняем/читаем count.
проблема в том что нужно внимательно перехватить все изменения того что мониторим при более сложных структурах

а вот для массивов придётся делать класс. увы(

правда так будет аккуратней:

```
class mineIOonLiveData<T>(private val _get: (T) -> T, private val _set: (T) -> T){
    private val pValue: MutableLiveData<T> by lazy {  MutableLiveData<T>() }
    fun observeValue(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<in T>) = pValue.observe(lifecycleOwner,observer)
    var value: T
        get() = _get(pValue.value!!)
        set(value) {pValue.value = _set(value)}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Короткий ответ: нет, нельзя.

Длинный ответ: Метод setValue в LiveData имеет модификатор доступа protected. Это значит доступ к этому методу есть только у наследников класса LiveData. Сделано это намеренно, и по хорошему создавая наследников вы не должны делать им открытых методов для изменения значения

Comment: я хочу перегрузить не setValue а создать LiveData которому скормлю что-то вроде 'var count: Int
        get() = if (чтото) field else 0
        set(value) {if (value>0) field = value}'

Comment: тогда придется создать класс в котором будет поле count с той логикой, которая заблагорассудится